# Symfony2 multiple choice is not validating

Tags: php, forms, symfony, multiple-choice

I'm creating a simple list of shop carts with users and products assigned to it.
My form for new cart looks like this:

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('cartName', 'text', array('label' =>'Nazwa koszyka:'))
        ->add('user', new UserForm(), array('data_class' => 'Zadanie\Bundle\Entity\User', 'label' => false))
        ->add('products','entity', array('label' => 'Wybierz produkty:', 'class' =>'Zadanie\Bundle\Entity\Product' , 'multiple' => true, 'required' => true))
        ->add('Zapisz', 'submit');
}
```

and everything is great except that i can submit the form even without selecting any product.

By far i just added "required" by jquery, but i don't like that. Can somebody explain to me why it is not working properly? :P

**EDIT:**
Here is the code from controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/cart/edit/{id}",name="_edit_cart")
 * @Template()
 */
public function editAction($id, Request $request)
{  
    $cart = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ZadanieBundle:Cart')->find($id);

    if($cart == null)
    {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Nie znaleziono rekordu');
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(new CartForm(), $cart);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isValid())
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();   
        $data = $form->getData();
        $em->persist($data);
        $em->flush();

        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->set('message', 'Koszyk zaktualizowano.');
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('_main_carts'));

    }

    return array('form' => $form->createView());
}
```

**SECOND EDIT:**

i found a **SOLUTION**, ( don't know if the best, but works :) ) so if anybody encounters that:

You have to create your validation file ( **validation.yml** for example) under YourBundle/Resources/config, in which you have to put information about properties. In my case it was:

```
Zadanie\Bundle\Entity\Cart:
properties:
    cartname:
        - NotBlank: ~
    user:
          - NotBlank: ~
constraints:
    - Callback:
        methods:
            -    [Zadanie\Bundle\Form\MyValidator, isUserValid]
```

and then i created MyValidator:

```
namespace Zadanie\Bundle\Form;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContextInterface;
use Zadanie\Bundle\Entity\Cart;

class MyValidator {

  public static function isUserValid(Cart $cart, ExecutionContextInterface $context)
  {
    if(!$cart->getUser()->getName())
        $context->addViolationAt('name', 'Proszę podać imię.', array(), null);
    if(!$cart->getUser()->getSurname())
        $context->addViolationAt('surname', 'Proszę podać nazwisko.', array(), null);
    if(count($cart->getProducts()) == 0)
        $context->addViolationAt('products', 'Proszę wybrać produkt.', array(), null);
 }
}
```

Comment: Provide some code (likely from your controller) that shows where you implement this form/handle the form submission. That will help us help you.

Comment: Also, show us you entity of your shopping cart...

Answer (score 0):

@Mati, regarding your first question about how the required option works, this option only sets the required attribute in HTML5 so does not do anything server side. From the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#form-validation)

> As of HTML5, many browsers can natively enforce certain validation
>   constraints on the client side. The most common validation is
>   activated by rendering a required attribute on fields that are
>   required. For browsers that support HTML5, this will result in a
>   native browser message being displayed if the user tries to submit the
>   form with that field blank.

Regarding your solution, that will certainly work though you may want to consider relying on the built-in [validators](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#constraints). I'm fairly sure the product count constraint can use the built-in [Count Collection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Count.html) constraint.